# Difference between OO and Grouped Functions?

Tags: oop, function

I have no knowledge of object-oriented programming features other than very light theory, so I was hoping somebody might be able to tell me how using objects is different from grouping functions like so:

```
void parent(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
if(a == ?)
{
    void child(int a, int b)
    {
        etc
    }
}

if(b == ?)
{
    void child(int c, int d)
    {
        etc
    }
}

if(c == ?)
{
    void child(int c, int b, int a)
    {
        etc
    }
}
}
```

Other than conflicting data type being passed to/from functions (in C, which I'm basing my knowledge on at the moment) and accessing a particular module of code being slightly more long-winded, what are the differences?

Hopefully I've made my question clear, whilst not coming across as too idiotic in the process. :)

Thanks.

Comment: You can emulate object-orientation without support from the lanugage, if that's your question. Of course, the necessary boilerplate code makes this rather impractical in practice (not entirely unhead of though - see implementations of object-oriented languages written in e.g. C, or quite a few file systems). Anyway, your example doesn't seem to make much sense - as of now, it shows lexically nested functions rather than anything OO-related.

Answer (score 0):

Objects can maintain internal state; they can expose that state (through accessors) or keep it completely private (as private variables).  The ability to maintain state that is inaccessible to any other execution unit is a major difference between what you're describing and OOP.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the concept of Functional programming an Object Oriented Programing is the question "Who's doing the work ?"

In **Functional** programming you have methods that perform operations on structures of data.

In **Object Oriented Programing** the idea is that the object themselves are working.

OOP in most cases gives you a more intuitive abstraction of a problem, and allows you to design more complicated structures while assigning roles to objects as players.

Of course under it all its just a bunch of code with functions calling each other. Just the concept is different.